# JSHTML not working on Express.js in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I don't seem to get JSHTML to work as a template engine on Express.js in Node.js. When I install my Express.js application and a basic application is created for me, and I run it I get this error message:

```
500 TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function
at View.render (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
at Function.app.render (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:677:7)
at exports.index (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/routes/index.js:7:7)
at callbacks (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:165:11)
at param (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139:11)
at pass (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:146:5)
at Router._dispatch (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
at Object.router (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (/Users/blackbook/nodejs/ds/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

My app.js looks like this (it's what Express.js created for me):

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jshtml');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

I have this installation:

- Node.js v.0.8.5
- Express.js@3.0.0rc2
- jshtml@0.2.3

Comment: Have you installed jshtml using npm?
Anyway, I think express 3.0 does not suppor jshtml yet. 

Express 3.0 has changed lot of things on layout.. Try using express 2.0 or just change to jade and test.

Comment: @RafaelMotta yes I have installed jshtml with npm. I've tried using express 2.0 but I can't get it to work either. Im looking for a template engine that can use a "masterpage" for my templates, and jshtml does that in a nice way. I've looked into EJS to, but that dosent seem to support it. I know jade can do it, but I dont like to write my templates in jade.

Comment: I think express provides the concept of master page, and not the template engine. In express 3.0 you dont have a layout anymore. But try using Eco templates.. it has the concept of a master page. It's like EJS, but u write the code in coffee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSHTML currently works with Express.js 2. There are plans on getting the engine to work with Express.js 3, but currently I am too busy with enjoying the summer! Expect a fix for this problem in the winter!

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x you can use  app.engine for 2-x compatibility.

e.g.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var jshtml = require("jshtml");
app.engine("jshtml", function (path, options, fn) {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, str) {
        if (err) return fn(err);
        str = jshtml.compile(str,options)(options).toString();
        fn(null, str);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

consolidate.js is used as a bridge between many template engines and express. If your engine isn't supported checkout the source code. Most engines need like 15 lines of code to implement.

Comment: If I look at jshtml on github I see that it works with express. But if I follow step by step there it still dosent work. So probably the support for jshtml is gone on express. :/ https://github.com/elmerbulthuis/jshtml

Comment: Express adjusted it's template system a little in 3.x so your template engine might not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working in my project and will probably issue a pull request soon but for now look at my comment in
https://github.com/elmerbulthuis/jshtml/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It works for me, as like you.

Firstly, install jshtml-express via npm and then do the following.

```
var app = express();
**app.engine('jshtml', require('jshtml-express'));**

// All environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jshtml');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I hope it will work for you as well.